# Doctrine 2 ORM Zend 2 Form Many to Many Example

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

Anyone have a good and complete example for many to many relation using ZF2 and Doctrine 2, especially when using ObjectMultiCheckBox ?
I found this tutorial - https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md but it don't explain how to do a many to many relation.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm in the exact same boat, I realized after reading this post and rereading the Doctrine I realized that a Many To Many might not be possible without creating the association manually and creating a one to many & a many to one. http://codemonkeys.be/2013/02/example-of-a-doctrine-2-x-many-to-many-association-class/

Comment: I advanced a little in this post and I think it is possible.
The answer is here https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md, but you need to play arround the doctrine hydrator strategy also (that is descibed also in the link provided).
Elsewhere the documentation is not complete and I think would be good if the contributors of Doctrine project will add an example for this case.

Comment: Yea I've gotten a little further too using that doc. Got my collection loaded into the checkbox but only way I can find to create the associations is to manually set & check the values of checkboxs then create/remove associations. Haven't implemented it fully because I feel like there should be a bindable way with field sets.

Answer (score 0):

K so I figured out how todo this eventually after realizing the hydrator wasn't binding associations and I had to create the link. I'm going to put a full blog post up explaining it but in case you're still stuck. If you want to look at all the code together I've got it up on [github (link)](https://github.com/Suiko6272/Website/tree/master/module/OmniBlog/src/OmniBlog/Form) mind you I'm actively learning/developing/cleaning it up so its a bit messy

Basically you need to collect the selected models, create the association link by adding them to the entity, then persist the entity WITH the cascade add/del active on Doctrine (or manually do it by persisting the link's before the entity).

Below example is a Many-to-Many between my Posts and Categories

You need to have cascade active on your **entity**'s property

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CategoryPostAssociation", mappedBy="category",  cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $category_post_associations;
```

You need to push the object manager from your Form to your fieldsets

**PostFieldSet**

```
$categoryFieldset = new CategoryFieldset($objectManager);
    $this->add(array(
        'type'    => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
        'name' => 'categories',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Select Categories',
            'object_manager' => $objectManager,
            'should_create_template' => true,
            'target_class'   => 'OmniBlog\Entity\Category',
            'property'       => 'title',
            'target_element' => $categoryFieldset,
          ),
    ));
```

and categoryfieldset just has a textbox of the Title.

In my **PostController**'s AddAction

```
public function addAction() {
    // Get your ObjectManager
    $objectManager = $this->getEntityManager();

    //Create the form and inject the ObjectManager
    //Bind the entity to the form
    $form = new PostForm($objectManager);
    $post = new Post();
    $form->bind($post);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            /*
            * Get IDs from form element
            * Get categories from the IDs
            * add entities to $post's categories list
            */
            $element = $form->getBaseFieldset()->get('categories'); //Object of: DoctrineModule\\Form\\Element\\ObjectMultiCheckbox
            $values = $element->getValue();

            foreach($values as $catID){
                $results = $objectManager->getRepository('OmniBlog\Entity\Category')->findBy(array('id' => $catID));
                $catEntity = array_pop($results);                   
                $link = $post->addCategory($catEntity);
                //Entity/Post 's association table cascades persists and removes so don't need to persist($link), but would be done here
            }

            $objectManager->persist($post);
            $objectManager->flush();

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute(
                static::ROUTE_CHILD,
                array('controller' => static::CONTROLLER_NAME
            ));
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

Above if you see $post->addCategory($catEntity); this leads to my Entity or Model managing the linking (I was passing back the link encase I want to handle the cascading manually)

**Post**

```
    /**
 * Returns the created $link
 */
public function addCategory(Category $category){
    $link = new CategoryPostAssociation();
    $link->setCategory($category);
    $link->setPost($this);
    $this->addCategoryPostAssociations($link);
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: The posted example follow the documentation, except that the form didn't contain the hydrator strategy and also after the form is validated there is a way to do a more simple persist, without much code that you have writed here. I will post here soon an example how i realized this case.

Answer (score -1):

Found an good blog where it is explained step by step what is need to be done - http://laundry.unixslayer.pl/2013/zf2-quest-zendform-many-to-many/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.