# Doctrine ObjectMultiCheckBox form many-to-many grouped

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a database like this

[image: model database]

And I need to make a form with checkboxes to save this to this database. Assume these are what my records look like

[image: db records]

For now, I have a form like this in which the user can't know witch action corresponds to which function

[image: actual form]

I'd like something like this where action and function appear together

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

My PHP code for creating the checkboxes is as follows:

```
        $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
        'name' => 'functionAction',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Functions:',
            'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
            'target_class' => 'Acl\Entity\FunctionAction',
            'label_generator' => function ($funcAction)
            {
                return $funcAction->getAction()->getDescription();
            },
            'is_method' => true,
            'find_method' => array(
                'name' => 'findByRole',
                'params' => array(
                    'role' => $this->getUser()->getRole()
                )
            )
        )
    ));
```

Comment: You could see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723340/doctrine-2-orm-zend-2-form-many-to-many-example

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is in view, I just need to group the actions by the functions, my back-end is working properly

Comment: Provide us some inside in how you render your multi checkbox. You might need to take a different approach to render the checkboxxes.

Comment: I edited ZF2 Checkbox class, I will post the solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **SOLUTION**

#### Options:

```
$options = array(
    'head_check_callback' => function ($last, $current)
    {
        return ! $last || $last->getFunction()->getId() != $current->getFunction()->getId();
    },
    'head_label_callback' => function (\Acl\Entity\FunctionAction $current)
    {
        $nome = $current->getFunction()->getDescription();
        return $current ? $nome : '';
    }
);
```

#### To render in view

```
$this->FormGroupMultiCheckbox()->setOptions($options)->render($this->form->get('functionAction'));
```

#### Edited CheckBox class

http://pastebin.com/UcDN8xVp

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer exactly your question. But if you want to let the user know witch action corresponds to which function, you may modify the function for `label_generator` to this one :

```
'label_generator' => function ($funcAction)
        {
           $action_desc = $funcAction->getAction()->getDescription();
           $function_desc =$funcAction->getFunction()->getDescription();
           return $action_desc.' '.$function_desc;
        },
```

so that you can have labels as : **create user**, **delete post**,...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This could work, but isn't the best way. My intention was to make collapsible items to select actions for each function

Comment: Perhaps you can do that with some javaScript using these labels. After the last checkbox with `(action) User` insert a `div` in which you can write the title **post**

Comment: Well, it's exactly what I need. But with javascript? ZF2 and Doctrine2 is amazing, I just need to know how can I use them for making this

Comment: Yes that would be great if you do it only with zf2 and doctrine2. I was searching for something similar but in vain.